# How to change json data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am getting back some data from a service and I am struggling to change the structure. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Current Structure:**

```
 {  
  "key1": {    
   "description":"lorem ipsum",  
  },  
  "key2": {    
   "description":"lorem ipsum",  
  } 
 }
```

**New Structure:**

```
[    
 {    
    "label":"key1",  
    "description":"lorem ipsum",  
 },    
 {  
    "label":"key2",  
    "description":"lorem ipsum",  
 }  
]
```

Comment: SO is not a free coding service, please share your efforts !

Comment: I was a little embarrassed Gilles Gouaillardet :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.map()` with `Object.keys()` and `Object.assign()`:

```js
let data = {  
  "key1": {    
   "description":"lorem ipsum",  
  },  
  "key2": {    
   "description":"lorem ipsum",  
  } 
};

let result = Object.keys(data)
                   .map(key => Object.assign({"label": key}, data[key]));

console.log(result);
```

Alternatively you can also use spread syntax:

```js
let data = {  
  "key1": {    
   "description":"lorem ipsum",  
  },  
  "key2": {    
   "description":"lorem ipsum",  
  } 
};

let result = Object.keys(data)
                   .map(key => ({"label": key, ...data[key]}));

console.log(result);
```

**Useful Resources:**

- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)
- [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)
- [`Spread syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Answer (score 2):

```js
const serverData = {  
  "key1": {    
   "description":"lorem ipsum",  
  },  
  "key2": {    
   "description":"lorem ipsum",  
  } 
 }

// Expected output:
/*[    
 {    
    "label":"key1",  
    "description":"lorem ipsum",  
 },    
 {  
    "label":"key2",  
    "description":"lorem ipsum",  
 }  
]*/

const expectedOutput = Object.keys(serverData)
  .map((key) => ({
    label: key,
    description: serverData[key].description
  }));
  
console.log(expectedOutput);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Object.keys`. This will give all the keys of the object. Now use `Array.map` function to create a new array using the array which was created using `Object.keys`

```js
var oldObj = {
  "key1": {
    "description": "lorem ipsum",
  },
  "key2": {
    "description": "lorem ipsum",
  }
}

var getKeys = Object.keys(oldObj);

var newObj = getKeys.map(function(item) {
  return {
    label: item,
    description: oldObj[item].description

  }
});
console.log(newObj)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var x =  {
            "key1": {
                "description":"lorem ipsum",
            },
            "key2": {
                "description":"lorem ipsum",
            }
        }

        var result = []
        for(var i=0; i< Object.keys(x).length; i++){
            var key = Object.keys(x)[i]
            var object = {"Key" : key, "description" : x[key].description}
            result.push(object)
        }
        console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should produce the array of object you requested in your post.

```
 var newlist = [];

for (var key in yourobject) {
    if (yourobject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
         var tmpobj = {};
         tmpobj.label = key;
         tmpobj.description = yourobject[key];
         newlist.push(tmpobj);
    }
}
```